Update global Inertia Variables (Laravel with Vue)
I'm using Inertia with VueJS, in the HandleInertiaRequests I have the variable 'foo':
 public function share(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'foo' => str()->random(1000)
        ];
    }

Exists a way to update this variable in a VueJS without refreshing the view?
<script setup>
const updateFoo = () => {
// do something here
}
</script>

<template>
{{ $page.props.foo }}

<button @click="updateFoo" type="button">update</button>
</template>


You can assign the value of foo to a state variable, and then interact with the state variable instead of the props value:
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const foo = ref(props.foo);

const updateFoo = () => {
// do something here
}
</script>

<template>
{{ foo }}

<button @click="updateFoo" type="button">update</button>
</template>

